# capturing multiple instances of a pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string:

```
{value1}+{value2}-{value3}*{value...n}
```

using a regular expression, I want to capture each of the bracketed values as well as the operators in between them and I do not know how many brackets there will be.

I tried:

```
/(\{.*\}).*([\+|\-|\*|\/])*/mgU
```

but that is just getting me the values and not the operators. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try matching with `\{[^{}]*}|[+\/*-]`

Comment: Try using use 2 capture groups where the second one is in a non capture group  `{([^{}]*)}(?:([-+*])|$)` https://regex101.com/r/9wi6Z0/1

Comment: Could you please confirm if your string will be always same format?

Comment: The string will have at least one part matching {value} but could also have several of those {value} matches separated by an operator +, -, * or /. My goal is to identify a string matching this pattern then pull the pieces apart to be used later in the perl script.

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/Wi8sKN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the string first with

```perl
/\A ({ [^{}]* }) (?: [\/+*-] (?1))* \z/x
```

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `({[^{}]*})` - Group 1: a `{`, any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}` char
- `(?:[\/+*-](?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of a `/`, `+`, `*` or `-` char and then the Group 1 pattern
- `\z` - end of string.

Then, you may collect individual matches with

```perl
/ { [^{}]* } | [\/+*-] /gx
```

This regex matches all occurrences of  any substrings between `{` and `}` (with `{[^{}]*}`) or `/`, `+`, `*` or `-` chars (with `[\/+*-]`).

See a [complete demo script](https://ideone.com/Wi8sKN):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
 
my $text = "{value1}+{value2}-{value3}*{value...n}";
 
if ($text =~ /\A ({ [^{}]* }) (?: [\/+*-] (?1))* \z/x) {
    while($text =~ / { [^{}]* } | [\/+*-] /gx) {
        print "$&\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{value1}
+
{value2}
-
{value3}
*
{value...n}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea might be using the `\G` anchor and 2 capture groups, where the curly values are in group 1 and the operator in group 2:

```
\G(?=.*{[^{}]*}\z)({[^{}]*})([+*\/-])?
```

The pattern matches

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, or at the start of the string (in this case)
- `(?=.*{[^{}]*}\z)` Positive lookahead, assert that the string ends with a curly part
- `({[^{}]*})` Capture the curly braces in group 1
- `([+*\/-])?` Optionally capture an operator in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VoALzD/1) | [Perl demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@3UkGluKRIwVZBqbosMac01bBWG8IwqtWFMIxrtSAMPT29vFola67yjMycVAUNiL46Bf0Ydw17Wz2tmOrouOraWK3amCpNDRhbUyNaWytGXzdW014/XVOhmksBCAqKMvNKFJScS4tyKhXARlspqBgq@BekFiWW5BcBOUYxeUCLav//BwA)

Example

```
my $str = "{value1}+{value2}-{value3}*{value...n}";
while ($str =~ /\G(?=.*\{[^{}]*}\z)({[^{}]*})([+*\/-])?/g) {
    print "Curly value: $1 Operator: $2\n";
}
```

Output

```
Curly value: {value1} Operator: +
Curly value: {value2} Operator: -
Curly value: {value3} Operator: *
Curly value: {value...n} Operator:
```

Answer (score 0):

The tokenizer approach:

```perl
my @tokens;
for ($str) {
   while (1) {
      /\G \s+ /xgc;

      /\G \{ ( [^{}]* ) \} /xgc
         and do { push @tokens, [ VALUE => $1 ]; next; };

      /\G ( [+-*\/] ) /xgc
         and do { push @tokens, [ OP => $1 ]; next; };

      /\G \Z /xgc
         and last;

      die( "Unexpected character at pos ".( pos )."\n" );
   }
}
```

It might be overkill, but it's easier to extend.

Comment: Without knowing what's possibly inside the braces, this is a good start. Otherwise, Dijkstra's two-stack calculator might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have non-nested blocks, separated by a known list of operators, you can use [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) to very easily separate a statement into values and operators.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @val = split m#([-+/*])#, <DATA>;   # parens will prevent operators from being consumed
print Dumper \@val;

__DATA__
{value1}+{value2}-{value3}*{valuen}/{value4}+{value5}-{value6}*{valuen}+{value7}+{value8}-{value9}
```

This will print:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '{value1}',
          '+',
          '{value2}',
          '-',
          '{value3}',
          '*',
          '{valuen}',
          '/',
          '{value4}',
          '+',
          '{value5}',
          '-',
          '{value6}',
          '*',
          '{valuen}',
          '+',
          '{value7}',
          '+',
          '{value8}',
          '-',
          '{value9}
'
        ];
```

From there, it should be a simple task to validate and clean up the values, as well as identify the operators.

Comment: I started on an answer like this because I love split's separator retention mode. As long as the values don't also have the operator characters it's clever.

Comment: @briandfoy It is a very simple solution, which is appealing.